# How to install last version of backport-iwlwifi-dkms?

Tags: drivers, apt, kernel, iwlwifi, backport

I'm on `Ubuntu 18.04 LTS`. My kenel version is: `5.4.0-122-generic`. I would like to install backport-iwlwifi-dkms version 8613. If I do:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install backport-iwlwifi-dkms
```

It automatically install backport-iwlwifi-dkms-7906. How can I install the specific 8613 version? Thank you so much? (I can only operate trought CLI)

Comment: How do you know that you need that specific version? It is unavailable in Ubuntu repositories for any release.

Comment: It is better to ask about your real problem to avoid [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: I'm following a specific guide, and I want to stay in the same conditions. I need /usr/src/backport-iwlwifi-8613

Comment: Why do you want to do this? It is an unusual sort of thing to want to do and as such it is highly likely to cause problems and probably leave you worse off than you already are. If you have a Wifi device that's not supported on your current kernel version (unlikely but possible) then just try installing the HWE kernel and stack. That is easy, safe and supported. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack

Comment: OP has the latest HWE version already.

Comment: @RDP1998 then the guide you are following is not using Ubuntu 18.04 I guess, or got it from somewhere other than `apt`.